# No Add Friend button

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

I have a similar problem as many. One of my real friends (a live human being), does not have an Add Friend button on her page. I've never been Facebook friends with her and also never blocked her. Is it possible she blocked me? Is there a setting she added that caused this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible that she has blocked you and then unblocked you. Blocking/unblocking or denying a friend request can cause this problem. A person  who receive request has always an option to deny request and report as a spam. Reporting spam make sure that sender will never be able to send request again to that person.

There are mainly three reason to not seeing "Add Friend" button:

1. As *Sathya* has mentioned in his [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/107739/87130), setting "Who can contact me" as "Friends of friends" and you both have not any mutual friends.
2. As I have mentioned above blocking/unblocking or denying request.
3. A person has reached 5000 friends limit and now cannot add more.

Your friend still can send a friend request to you except in third case.

If these are not your case, please [report a problem to Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/1126628984024935?helpref=hc_global_nav).

Comment: if you're blocked, you won't be able to see the person's profile page at all..

Comment: Correct, that is why I mentioned _possible that she has **blocked you and then unblocked you**._

Comment: I missed that. good call.

Answer (score 2):

There's an option where a person can opt for only Friends of Friends to be able to send friend requests. Possibly you don't have any mutual friends on Facebook

[image]